# JS(TypeScript) 連想配列　検索処理について

Tags: javascript, typescript

**やりたいこと**
・JS(TypeScript)の連想配列において、階層を取得し、特定階層以上はfalseにしたい。

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "フォルダA",
    folder:[
    {
      "id":2,
      "name":"フォルダA-2"
    },
    {
      "id":3,
      "name":"フォルダA-3"
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "フォルダB"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "フォルダC",
    folder:[
    {
      "id":6,
      "name":"フォルダC-1",
      folder:[
      {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "フォルダC-1-1"
      }]
    }]
  }
]
```

上記のような入れ子構造のデータがあります。
また、folderプロパティは必須ではない・idは一意です。

特定のidの階層を数え、特定の階層以上だった場合はfalseを返すメソッドを作成したいのですが、思い付かず悩んでいます。（再帰処理？）
ご教授頂けないでしょうか。

例：id=6 の場合は、countNode=1としたい。id=7の場合は、countNode=2としたい。(dataは上記のデータ全ての想定)
countNode>=10の場合はfalse

```
const countNode(currentId:string,data:any):boolean => {
  const node = 0;
  const maxNode = 10;
  //以下処理悩み中。
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

参考: https://repl.it/repls/CyanWiseQueries

TSということなので、まずは対象となるデータ配列の要素をモデル化しておくと、次のように書けます:

```
interface Data {
  id: number
  name: string
  folder?: Data[]
}
```

このような要素をもつデータ配列において、ある`id`をもつ要素の“深さ”は、ご指摘のとおり再帰処理で簡単に取得できます:

```
const scanDepth = (data: Data[], id: number, depth: number = 0): number => {
  for (const d of data) {
    if (d.id === id) return depth
    if (d.folder) {
      const ret = scanDepth(d.folder, id, depth + 1)
      if (ret !== -1) return ret
    }
  }
  return -1
}

// for example
console.assert(scanDepth(DATA, 1) === 0)
console.assert(scanDepth(DATA, 6) === 1)
console.assert(scanDepth(DATA, 7) === 2)
```

あとは、`scanDepth`関数の返り値を判定すればよいでしょう（こまかい条件は必要に応じて直してください）:

```
const verifyDepth = (data: Data[], id: number, maxdepth: number): boolean => scanDepth(data, id) < maxdepth

// for example
console.assert(verifyDepth(DATA, 1, 1))
console.assert(verifyDepth(DATA, 6, 2))
console.assert(verifyDepth(DATA, 7, 3))
console.assert(!verifyDepth(DATA, 7, 2))
console.assert(!verifyDepth(DATA, 7, 1))
console.assert(!verifyDepth(DATA, 7, 0))
```

ただし、`scanDepth`はナイーブな実装なので、必要以上に深く探索をするかもしれません。データ構造がかなり深くなることが事前に予測できるならば、探索を打ち切るなど改良の余地はあると思います。

Answer (score 1):

個人的な経験則ですが、ツリー状のデータ構造の場合、データを探索する関数に再帰処理が多く発生し、デバッグがしづらかったり、メンテナンスがしづらかったりします。

あくまでデータが数十万、数百万とない前提で処理を組むと一度データ構造をユニークキーでフラット化すると様々な処理が簡素に書くことが可能です。

もし、メモリーの消費を抑えて、高速な処理を求めるならば、この方法ではないもの探すと良いでしょう。

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHsA2ATayDeAsAFDLLDYBcyIArgLYBG0A3CWSHPRNQM5hRQAczalkMLLigB+ahhzQA2gF1RAXxIkA9ACod7HeWyAZBkAAcoHhDQFYMgFg1AECqBABgDyjAFYQEYQHYMAaQgBPQAsGQHUGQDMGQGc9QDN1QDRlQE0GQGiGAy0SUEhYRBRUTDgweSkCdmRFCmo6JmhlaiIxMgAHOCgIcABJbFkaBmYoUTJa7IALADkuCF4+AWEVbuQ1dU1iBHQQfmR6OABrCEzs3LwAXmQACgKJBShRtEklZQAaY6ycy6g5e52oZH38NVuxOobm1pKHWgJAAlM9to93gA+fJiE5SXgAOgkUAAoog+gcDvDoCDobCesgFkswMhfo0Hqd3mT6hSWsgAGQM8QvR6Kcn-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-Js1KAGFMolfTCmcniTLigA2HzCWSgKSrQzDytqyrxNC2rYtq6SAHZGqsoqUo01rMLajraumYayEi2rsolBaeiWrliEAvjSQgyF9gDTYmxDATW3-Mgi27JD0CEbFDrbHC+IuzAroOEsyyYg4GpzE7-1dDbiHYkADn-IA)

```js
interface Folder {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  folder?: Folder[];
}

/**
 * idが一意な場合、ObjectのKeyとして平坦化する
 */
interface FlatFolder {
  [id: number]: {
    parentId?: number;
    pathNames: string[];
  };
}

const makeFlatFolder = (
  folders: Folder[],
  flatFolder: FlatFolder = {},
  parentId?: number
): FlatFolder => {
  folders.forEach((folder) => {
    const parentFolder = parentId && flatFolder[parentId];
    flatFolder[folder.id] = {
      parentId,
      pathNames: parentFolder
        ? [...parentFolder.pathNames, folder.name]
        : [folder.name],
    };
    if (folder.folder) {
      makeFlatFolder(folder.folder, flatFolder, folder.id);
    }
  });
  return flatFolder;
};

const countNode = (folderId: number, flatFolder: FlatFolder): boolean => {
  if (!flatFolder[folderId]) {
    throw new Error(`FlatFolderに該当のfolderId: "${folderId}"が存在しません`);
  }
  const depth = flatFolder[folderId].pathNames.length - 1;
  const maxNode = 10;
  return depth < maxNode;
};

const main = () => {
  const rootFolder: Folder[] = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "フォルダA",
      folder: [
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "フォルダA-2",
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "フォルダA-3",
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "フォルダB",
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: "フォルダC",
      folder: [
        {
          id: 6,
          name: "フォルダC-1",
          folder: [
            {
              id: 7,
              name: "フォルダC-1-1",
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ];

  const flatFolder = makeFlatFolder(rootFolder);
  console.log(flatFolder);
  console.log(countNode(6, flatFolder));
};

main();
```